# Get row and column number from mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, mouse-cursor

I am using Ace for my in browser text editor.

```
editor.on("mousemove", function (e)
{
  // use clientX clientY to get row and column locations
});
```

From clientX clientY coordinates i need actual row and column number on the editor.

Looking at Ace api but cant find anything related.

Do you know any way i can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: For anyone looking for a generic answer: `<script>function getCursorPosition() { var p;var editor = ace.edit("editor");p = editor.selection.getCursor();} </script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

```
editor.on("mousemove", function (e)
{
   var position = e.getDocumentPosition();
});
```

found it looking inside event object in chrome debugger.